# ¿Por que al crecer la ruta mi css no se aplica?

Tags: javascript, css, nodejs, express, ejs

mi problema es el siguiente:

Este es mi archivo estático donde pondré imágenes y el css:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Establecí una ruta de ejemplo y todo bien:

```
app.use('/prueba', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al crecer la ruta:

```
app.use('/prueba/prueba', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
```

No reconoce el css , a que se debe esto?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando EJS , pero esto tambien me pasa con handlebars. Nose si falte configurar algo o estoy haciendo algo mal. Gracias !

Este es el codigo de mi plantilla ejs que quiero reutilizar en todas las paginas, cuando la Ruta es por ejemplo http://localhost/prueba funciona el css , pero cuando la ruta se cambia a http://localhost/prueba/prueba ,no .Intente en ese caso cambiar el link a : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app.css">` y funciono , pero no se si sea lo correcto trabajarlo asi

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: ¿En el HTML se está usando una ruta relativa para hacer referencia al CSS?

Comment: te estaría faltando un `/` en `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">`